# Try to solve the “Mexican Puzzle”?

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Can you solve this puzzle I created last week?
[image: The Mexican Puzzle]

Comment: perhaps people could use a hint. (I know I could) There are some things that seem interesting but nothing that's penciled out so far.  Did others solve this where you made this for?